# "Could not find the specified key "ProductsLandingPageTitle" or class id "ProductsResources"" in Sitefinity

Tags: .net, sitefinity-4

I add sample product module to my project, set it as show in documentation, and after restart application get error.
Removing registry string from SystemConfig.config don't solve problem.

```
Could not find the specified key "ProductsLandingPageTitle" or class id "ProductsResources".
```

**Stack Trace:**

```
[ArgumentException: Could not find the specified key "ProductsLandingPageTitle" or class id "ProductsResources".]
Telerik.Sitefinity.Localization.Resource.GetString(ResourceDataProvider provider, String classId, String key, CultureInfo culture, Boolean falback, Boolean throws) +454
Telerik.Sitefinity.Localization.Res.Get(String classId, String key, CultureInfo culture, Boolean fallback, Boolean throws) +168
Telerik.Sitefinity.Abstractions.AppSettings.GetResourceValue(String resourceClassId, String resourceKey, CultureInfo culture) +125
Telerik.Sitefinity.Descriptors.LstringPropertyDescriptor.GetValueFromResource(String value, CultureInfo culture) +121
Telerik.Sitefinity.Descriptors.LstringPropertyDescriptor.TryGetResourceValue(Object component, String& value, CultureInfo culture) +140
Telerik.Sitefinity.Descriptors.LstringPropertyDescriptor.GetValue(Object component, CultureInfo culture, Boolean throwException, CultureInfo[] defaultCultures) +58
Telerik.Sitefinity.Descriptors.LstringPropertyDescriptor.GetValue(Object component, CultureInfo culture, Boolean throwException) +71
Telerik.Sitefinity.Descriptors.LstringPropertyDescriptor.GetString(Object component, CultureInfo culture, Boolean fallback) +100
Telerik.Sitefinity.Model.Lstring.GetString(CultureInfo culture, Boolean fallback) +64
Telerik.Sitefinity.Model.Lstring.get_Value() +35
Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.PageSiteNode..ctor(SiteMapBase provider, PageNode pageNode) +2725
Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.SiteMapBase.GetChildNodes(SiteMapNode node, Boolean ifAccessible) +470
Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.SiteMapBase.GetChildNodes(SiteMapNode node) +12
System.Web.SiteMapNode.get_ChildNodes() +30
System.Web.SiteMapNode.get_HasChildNodes() +10
Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI.Backend.MainMenu.IsNodeEmpty(PageSiteNode node) +30
Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI.Backend.MainMenu.<IsNodeEmpty>b__6(PageSiteNode c) +4
System.Linq.WhereArrayIterator`1.MoveNext() +55
System.Linq.Enumerable.Count(IEnumerable`1 source) +200
Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI.Backend.MainMenu.IsNodeEmpty(PageSiteNode node) +252
Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI.Backend.MainMenu.<IsNodeEmpty>b__6(PageSiteNode c) +4
System.Linq.WhereArrayIterator`1.MoveNext() +55
System.Linq.Enumerable.Count(IEnumerable`1 source) +200
Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI.Backend.MainMenu.IsNodeEmpty(PageSiteNode node) +252
Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI.Backend.MainMenu.CreateRadMenuItemFromNode(SiteMapNode node) +100
Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI.Backend.MainMenu.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +408
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +98
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +168
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +168
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +168
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3488
```

What could cause these problems?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to add the resource class id, before initializing the Resource class should have something like

`[ObjectInfo("ProductsResources", ResourceClassId = "ProductsResources")]`

Answer (score 1):

This is related to localization. The ProductsResources class is where these keys would be defined, and I'm guessing that key is missing...

you can also simply disable localization by removing the ResouceClassId property whenever it's set

I hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Add this

```
ResourceClassId=ProductCatalogSample.ProductsResources
```

while registering the module